# Harmonic partial sum calculator with multithreading

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads

I wrote a program which computes the harmonic partial sum to N terms with multithreading capability. I've been working on this to sharpen my C++ skills for the upcoming semester. Just wondering if there's anything that doesn't follow the C++ standard and/or glaringly wrong. Also wondering if I can make any further optimizations.

Basically I have my program set up to only use threads if the input is divisible by 4, since I am using 4 threads due to my quad core CPU. I want this to be more flexible but I haven't thought of a better solution yet. If anyone has a suggestions, that'd be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_THREADS = 4;

// H(N) is defined to be the harmonic partial sum to N terms.
// calculateHarmonic(): function given to threads to compute H(N).
// unsigned long start: starting point for the loop; different for each thread.
// unsigned long N: amount of terms to compute; different for each thread; divided evenly by # of threads.
// double *sum: pointer to a double which holds a thread's individual sum for H(N).
void calculateHarmonic(long long start, long long N, double *sum)
{
    for(; start <= N; start++)
    {
        *sum += 1.0/start;
    }
}

void executeWithThreads(long long N)
{
    thread t[NUM_THREADS];  // using four threads
    double sum[NUM_THREADS] = {0.0};    // array of each sum calculated by each thread
    double finalSum = 0.0;  
    clock_t start = clock();

    // Assign threads their task.
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        // thread([name of function], [starting point], [N], [address of individual element in sum array])
        t[i] = thread(calculateHarmonic, (((N/4)*i)+1), ((N/4)*(i+1)), &(sum[i]));
    }

    // Join threads to terminate and sum up all individual sums into finalSum.
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        t[i].join();
        finalSum += sum[i];
    }

    clock_t end = clock();
    printf("Harmonic sum of %lld is %1.18lf\n", N, finalSum);
    printf("Calculation took %1.18lf seconds.\n", (((double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC))/NUM_THREADS);
}

void executeNoThreads(long long N)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        sum += 1.0/i;
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    printf("Harmonic sum of %lld is %1.18lf\n", N, sum);
    printf("Calculation took %1.18lf seconds.\n", (((double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC))/NUM_THREADS);
}

int main()
{
    long long N;

    cout << "Enter the amount of terms to calculate the Harmonic sum to: ";
    cin >> N;
    assert(N > 0 && "N must be a nonzero positive integer.");
    cout << endl;

    if(N > NUM_THREADS && N % 4 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Calculating with threads..." << endl;
        executeWithThreads(N);
    }
    else if(N > NUM_THREADS && N % 4 != 0)
    {
        cout << "Calculating without threads..." << endl;
        executeNoThreads(N);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Calculating without threads due to small N..." << endl;
        executeNoThreads(N);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -Ofast harm_sum.cpp -o harm.out ; ./harm.out
```

Comment: I would stay away from the old `clock` functions now that we have [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Try not to use `using namespace std` in global scope.  If you must use it, keep it in local scope, such as in a function.  More info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- I don't need any need to use `printf()` over `std::cout` here.  You are also using C-style casting and no `std::` for `clock_t`, so some of this code still looks C-like.

  If you're using `printf()` because you're having trouble with formatting, then take a look at the [`<iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) library for something useful.
- Unless you're debugging, `assert` may be unnecessary.  You can easily output an error message to `std::cerr` and return `EXIT_FAILURE` from `main()`.
- The value `4` used in `main()` appears to be a magic number and should be a constant.
- Each use of `std::endl` flushes the buffer and takes extra time. Luckily, you're not using it in the timed section.  It's still not needed in most cases and you can also output a newline with `"\n"`, which doesn't do a flush as well.  More info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you should prefer to use `std::async` over naked use of threads. There are a few reasons for this: firstly, `std::async` can actually return a value (wrapped in a `std::future`), which means less mucking about with passing out parameters by pointer/reference, and secondly because (unless explicitly specified with launch flags) it will leave it up to the runtime to coordinate and dispatch threads appropriately.

This would look something like:

```
double calculate_harmonic(long long start, long long N)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (; start <= N; ++start)
    {
        sum += 1.0 / start;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const std::size_t n_async = 4;
    const std::size_t N = 150;
    std::array<std::future<double>, n_async> futures;
    for (auto i = 0U; i < n_async; ++i) {
        futures[i] = std::async(calculate_harmonic, ((N / 4) * i) + 1,
            ((N / 4) * (i + 1)));
    }

    double final_sum = 0.0;
    for (auto&& future : futures) {
        final_sum += future.get();
    }
    std::cout << "final sum: " << final_sum << "\n";
}
```

Note that this also cleans up having to do annoying things like call `join()`.

The other nitpick is that for large harmonic series, you likely want to start with the **smallest** value and work your way backwards. The reason for this is because of the wonderful complexities of floating point arithmetic, but basically, floating point is not associative: a + b is not guaranteed to be equal to b + a for all floating point operands. To preserve as much precision as possible, you generally want to start working from smallest to largest value.

Comment: Good answer!  I'd suggest that you could set the value of `n_async = std::thread::hardware_concurrence()` and then reset it to a fallback value of `1` if `hardware_concurrence()` returns `0`.

Comment: @Yuushi Thanks for the response. I've spent some time researching and implementing what you've suggested. I'm sort of struggling to grasp `auto&&` actually is. Do you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Edward By the way, it's actually `hardware_concurrenc*y*()`. I copied your answer and it scared me with all the errors that popped up, haha.

Comment: :)  Sorry for the typo!  Looks like I made the same error twice, so I hope it didn't waste too much of your time.

Comment: @Yuushi Regarding the floating point order, my test runs have shown to have the the opposite effect of what you've suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisTarazi `auto&&` is a bit tricky, but effectively it can bind to an lvalue, a const lvalue, or an rvalue. In this case you can replace it with `(auto& future : futures)` if that's more understandable to you.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result) makes for some interesting reading regarding summation of values with large magnitude differences.